# Issue with moveTo block

Tags: anylogic

I have made an ASRS system show in image 3
An AGV that picks the agent from previous process and drops of at the entrance of conveyor showed in the image 3. The logic in image 1 works well for sometime but after that there pops up an error shown in image 2.

I am not sure why this is happening, can anyone please help me with this?

[Logic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wY6jc.png)

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZ6U3.png)

[ASRS 2D](https://i.stack.imgur.com/getlk.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably one of the best error messages that AnyLogic provides (most are quite cryptic).

It describes quite well what the problem is (there is a blockage downstream) and how to solve it (remove the downstream blockage or use Pull).

So not much more to say. Ensure that there is a queue between the MoveTo and `ASRSenter` and you are golden. Or ensure to empty your conveyor entry area before the next agent arrives

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But in the ASRSenter there are no agents inside. The no of agents in and out are same, which means there is no blockage right? But please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: no, the blockage can be further downstream. Try it out